# PHP variables lost their values?

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to build a template-loader system with PHP. Here's what I got so far:

config.php:

```
<?php
$style_assets_path = "/includes/styles/";
$template = "";
if ($_GET['pageid'] <= 100) {
    $template = "/main/main.php";
}
function loadTemplate() {
    global $style_assets_path;
    global $template;
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . $style_assets_path . "templates" . $template;
}
?>
```

home.php:

```
<?php
$page_title = "Homepage";
$menu_selected = "active";
$menu_selected_2 = "";
$menu_selected_3 = "";
$menu_selected_4 = "";
$content_heading = "Featured Content";
$page_contents = "";
$special_id = "home";

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php"; 

if ($_GET['pageid'] !== '1'){
    header('Location: /home.php?pageid=1');
    exit(0);
}

loadTemplate();
?>
```

So the variables:

```
$page_title = "Homepage";
$menu_selected = "active";
$menu_selected_2 = "";
$menu_selected_3 = "";
$menu_selected_4 = "";
$content_heading = "Featured Content";
$page_contents = "";
$special_id = "home";
```

don't have their values even if declared?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `$template = "/main/main.php";` want to be `$template = "/main/home.php";`

Comment: This is not a way I'd advise to build a template engine. Have a look how other frameworks/people solved this problem and you can learn alot! The problem with your code probably is that within the scope of `loadTemplate()` the variables aren't declared (global)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `require_once` inside a function, so only local variables and ones declared `global` will be available to the required file.

```
function loadTemplate() {
    global $style_assets_path;
    global $template;
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . $style_assets_path . "templates" . $template;
}
```

You would need to declare all these variables global, like so.

```
function loadTemplate() {
    global $style_assets_path,
           $template,
           $page_title,
           $menu_selected,
           $menu_selected_2,
           $menu_selected_3,
           $menu_selected_4,
           $content_heading,
           $page_contents,
           $special_id;
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . $style_assets_path . "templates" . $template;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It's not clear how the files are organized, but it might be necessary to set all the variables with `global`.

```
global $page_title = "Homepage";
```

As said in the comments, this is probably not the best way to make a template engine.

Comment: This time it really worked, but if I add these vars in the global file config.php then every page that requires it (contact.php/about.php) will have, for example `<title>My website &bull; <?= "$page_title"; ?></title>` which will output: `<title>My website &bull; Homepage</title>`... Let's just clear this out and I'll accept this answer.

Comment: OK, but how to set the different values for these variables if I am using only 1 template file?

Comment: You can re-assign the variables with `global $page_title = "Homepage";` anywhere before you include the template files.

Comment: Something like this? `global $page_title = "Homepage"; loadTemplate();`

Comment: Yes, that's the solution! I declared the variables as `global` inside the function and then put them and their values, e.g. `$page_title = "Homepage"` to the relevant/appropriate page. With this, the problem was solved, answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`include()` and `require()` work as if you've literally cut/pasted the included text into the location where you called `include()`/`require()`. Since you're doing your `include()` INSIDE a function call, the variables you set are inside that function's scope. When you return from the function, the variables are destroyed as part of the post-function cleanup.

e.g. consider this:

inc.php:

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar';
```

test.php:

```
<?php

function baz() {
   include('inc.php');
   echo "Inside baz(): $foo\n";
}
baz();
echo "Outside baz(): $foo\n";
```

You get this as output:

```
inside baz(): bar
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo in /home/marc/test.php on line 9
Outside baz():
```

Note how the "outside" output produced an undefined variable notice.